# What's the meaning of the phrase"while the fit is on us"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality

> I went up to the accountant's wicket and poked the ball of money at him with a quick convulsive movement as if I were doing a conjuring trick.
>
> My face was ghastly pale.
>
> "Here," I said, "deposit it." The tone of the words seemed to mean, "Let us do this painful thing **while the fit is on us**."

This story is *My Financial Career* by Stephen Leacock.

I need satisfactory answer, which i didn't get elsewhere?

Comment: Please see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fit) **noun (2)** 2: a sudden burst or flurry (as of activity). Or, while this *madness* is upon us.

Comment: "On" is used in which sense?

Comment: See [this on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/323661/explanation-of-the-clause)

Comment: I Could not get that better...